# The meaning of "scope" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

As detailed in Section 5.15, “Additional Capabilities of the ApplicationContext”, ApplicationContext instances in Spring can be **scoped**. In the Web MVC framework, each DispatcherServlet has its own WebApplicationContext, which inherits all the beans already defined in the root WebApplicationContext

I can't figure out what the "scoped" mean in this sentence...does it mean range or extent?

Comment: To look at or examine thoroughly (0LED).

Answer (score 1):

**Scope** in programming lingo has a special meaning.

From Wikipedia's *[Scope (computer programming)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29)*:

> In computer programming, the scope of a name binding – an association of a name to an entity, such as a variable – is the part of a computer program where the binding is valid: where the name can be used to refer to the entity.

I hate just pasting whole wiki pages so I think you'll get the most out of reading the definition there as I'm not particularly versed in programming lingo.